# Is there a Maven build for eclipselink that makes the OSGi bundles run in Felix and others?

Tags: maven-2, osgi, eclipselink

The Eclipselink OSGi bundles seem have trouble working in some OSGi containers, notably Felix, because they fail to import packages (and that are exported by the system) that they actually require. One example is the missing import of `javax.xml.namespace` in the `core` bundle of the current 1.1.3 release.

The eclipselink team has targeted this type of issues by using the BND tool for the build process in versions 1.2 and 2.0, so once these are out, we can expect this problem to be gone.

In the meantime, has anybody set up and published a Maven build from the eclipselink sources that does the bundling right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the version in the [SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository](http://www.springsource.com/repository/app/)? It looks like their [Eclipselink bundles](http://www.springsource.com/repository/app/search?query=eclipselink&type=bundlesByName&includeLibraries=true&_includeLibraries=on&includeBundles=true&_includeBundles=on&version=) are importing `javax.xml.namespace` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's the pom.xml file](http://github.com/thecarlhall/open-experiments/blob/master/slingtests/osgikernel/bundles/jpa/pom.xml) we use create a bundle that has EclipseLink and exposes JPA.  This bundle only has EclipseLink so you should be able to use it directly.